# How to encrypt the content of a file returned by Nodejs in a download API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

Basically, I have an API endpoint that allows users to send a POST request to download a CSV file.
The file is downloaded success but if I check the `Preview/Response tab` from `Chrome Dev tool` of this download request then the file's content is displayed here in human-readable (plain text) format.

Same results with both `res.download()` or `res.sendFile()` methods. I also configured https (Let's encrypt certificate) for both client and server domains, also additional SSL for Nodejs application.

I understand that these SSL configured will only prevent requests intercepted without encrypting the file's content in response data.

How can I download a file without displaying its content in the `Preview/Response tab`?

Any suggestion related to modifying Nodejs code or additional Nginx config will be appreciated.

Comment: If the client is downloading the file, would you not expect them to be able to inspect the file eventually?

Comment: Of course, users sure want to check their files.

Comment: You can't (there must be a duplicate around here somewhere so I won't make an answer) unless you encrypt the data using some non-SSL approach … but then if you want to do anything with it on the client you'll need to write code to decrypt it on the client … which means that you have to give that code to the user of the browser and it still won't be a secret. You can't give the browser data and keep the data secret from the owner of the browser.